# Rails: undefined method `title' for nil:NilClass

Tags: ruby-on-rails

So I've searched this and most people have gotten this error because they have their private method in the middle of their Class or they have records in the db that have nil attributes. As it stands, I only have one record in the db, which I will show below. I get this error when trying to access an index page I'm creating.

Controller:

```
class AnthologiesController < ApplicationController
    before_action :authenticate_user!, :except => [:show, :index]

    def index
        @anthologies = Anthology.all
    end

    def show
        @anthology = Anthology.find(params[:id])
    end

    def new
        @anthology = Anthology.new
    end

    def create
        @anthology = Anthology.new(anthology_params)
        @anthology.user = current_user

        if @anthology.save
            redirect_to @anthology, notice: "Success! Your anthology was created."
        else
            render 'new'
        end
    end

    private
    def anthology_params
        params.require(:anthology).permit(:title, :description)
    end
end
```

View:

```
<h1>Anthologies</h1>
<ul>
    <%= @anthologies.each do |anthology| %>
        <li><%= @anthology.title %></li>
        <li><%= @anthology.description %></li>
        <li><%= @anthology.username %></li>
    <% end %>
</ul>
```

And the one record in the db:

```
#<Anthology id: 1, title: "Writing More Better", description: "This is me teaching you writing and suchwhat.", created_at: "2015-11-26 15:57:40", updated_at: "2015-11-26 15:57:40", user_id: 1>
```

Any help would be amazing, and thanks in advance.

Comment: `@anthology != anthology`

Comment: Much thanks, the differences there are confusing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Inside the `each` loop you are referring to `@anthology` instead of the block variable you are declaring.

```
<h1>Anthologies</h1>
<ul>
    <%= @anthologies.each do |anthology| %>
        <li><%= anthology.title %></li>
        <li><%= anthology.description %></li>
        <li><%= anthology.username %></li>
    <% end %>
</ul>
```

Comment: That was the solution, I wasn't even aware of that.

Comment: Please mark the answer as solution if it's correct.

Answer (score 0):

Even you can also try this:

```
<h1>Anthologies</h1>
<ul>
  <%= @anthologies.each do |anthology| %>
    <li><%= anthology.try(:title) %></li>
    <li><%= anthology.try(:description) %></li>
    <li><%= anthology.try(:username) %></li>
  <% end %>
</ul>
```